# How to add custom emoji to bot embed with nextcord

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, emoji, nextcord

I am creating a discord bot with nextcord and for part of it, it embeds a message. I want to add custom emojis in the embed but nothing seems to be working.
My current code:

```
emoji = nextcord.Emoji(779407403804393512)
newEmbed.add_field(name = f"{emoji}" + " Talismans ➜ " + talismans, value = top_items_talismans, inline = False)


ERROR:
TypeError: Emoji.__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Other things I have tried:

```
emoji = nextcord.Emoji("779407403804393512")
/
emoji = nextcord.Emoji("fairysoul", "779407403804393512")
/
emoji = nextcord.Emoji(name = "fairysoul", id = "779407403804393512")
/
#name of my bot initialization is bot
emoji = bot.get_emoji(id = "fairysoul", id = 779407403804393512)
```

Also tried a fix from a different post:

```
from discord import Embed, Emoji
from discord.ext.commands import Bot

bot = Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def debug(ctx, emoji: Emoji):
    embed = Embed(description=f"emoji: {emoji}", title=f"emoji: {emoji}")
    embed.add_field(name="id", value=repr(emoji.id))
    embed.add_field(name="name", value=repr(emoji.name))
    await bot.say(embed=embed)

bot.run("token")
```

Nothing seems to be working please help

PS: I am using nextcord because I read somewhere that discord.py was discontinued, but I found out that it was restarted... Would it be better to switch to discord.py?

EDIT: SOLVED

Comment: I believe `discord.py` and `nextcord` are pretty similar. The thing is, you can't instantiate `Emoji` objects in either library. If you simply want to display it, it's `<:my_emoji:1234567>` or for animated `<a:my_emoji:12345678>` where `my_emoji` is its name.

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix. First, I switched to discord.py which was easier than I thought as most of the functions and documentation is the same. I added the custom emojis to my own server (in which the bot is located) and used:

```
emoji = get(ctx.message.guild.emojis, name= 'name')
```

Sorry for the repeated question, I was previously only looking for a nextcord fix which I couldn't really find.